# Adding time from string into date object swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift4

I have a time coming from service in string form like so "12:30 PM".

I am able to get this time but I want to add this time in current date. like so

```
31/3/2021 12:30 PM
```

The current date is in date object and coming time is in string format.

Please let me know what is a right way to do so? I am right now taking 12, 30,from string and setting it via Calendar. But dont know how to set am pm . Please let me know how to append time with date object. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, if that is the date string you are getting from your service, it is incomplete. It needs a time zone.

Here's what I would do:

1. Assuming the service always uses the same time zone, find out that time zone.
2. Create a date formatter for that date string format, including the AM/PM bit.
3. Set the date formatter to use the time zone from step 1.
4. Convert the date string to a Date object using your DateFormatter.
5. Use the current calendar to extract the hours and minutes values into a DateComponents object.
6. Get the current date, and use the Calendar function `date(bySettingHour:minute:second:of:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)` to set the hour and minutes of the current date to the values you got from step 5.

You should search in the Xcode help system for:

- Dates and Times (overview)
- Calendrical calculations (discussion specific to doing math on dates and times)
- DateFormatter. (See [**this article**](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for info on the characters to use to build your dateFormat string.)
- Calendar
- DateComponents

Calendar

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Try your hand at the steps I posted, and if you are unable to get it working, edit your question to show what you've tried and we can help you get it working.

Comment: thank you, i havenot done anything. If you can help by posting script then its ok. Thanks anways

Comment: No, I am not going to write the "script" (code) for you. Try it yourself and if you can't get it working edit your question to show what you've tried and what's not working and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting up your `DateFormatter` with the correct `timeZone`, `calendar`, `defaultDate`, and `dateFormat`. Here's an example:

```
import Foundation

let parser = DateFormatter()
parser.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
parser.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "US/Eastern")!
parser.defaultDate = parser.calendar!.date(
    from: DateComponents(
        timeZone: parser.timeZone!, era: 1,
        year: 2021, month: 3, day: 31,
        hour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0))!
parser.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

print(parser.date(from: "12:30 PM"))
```

Output:

```
Optional(2021-03-31 16:30:00 +0000)
```